# How to place two input fields side by side in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have 3 input fields, the first one I want by itself, but the next two I need side by side. So far I tried to add a className row to the ones that need to be side by side, but they still show up below each other

```
 {pillTabs.selected === 4 && (
                <div>
                   <div className="row"> //need the ones in this div side by side
                   <Input
                    label="Name"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter name"
                    inputId="basicInput"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
                  ></Input>
                  <Input
                    label="Label"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter label"
                    inputId="basicInput"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
                  ></Input>
                   </div>
                </div>
                  )}
```

Is it possible to get them side by side without using an external library like bootstrap?

Comment: This sounds like a styling issue, not a React or JavaScript issue.  What styling is being applied to these elements?  What CSS rules have you written to change their styling?  Looking at the resulting HTML along with the CSS being applied to it is likely to be more useful debugging than just looking at the JSX code.

Comment: What about using a TABLE? That's what I normally do

Comment: You should look into using material-ui or add bootstrap (only really need the css). Both frameworks have grid systems that make handling spacing and alignment very easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flex` from CSS like:

```
.side-by-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

<div>
  <Input1 />
  <div className="side-by-side">
    <Input2 />
    <Input3 />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this worked. How can I add space between these inputs though? I tried to do margin-right: 20px; but that didn't do anything

Comment: So.. There are several approaches.. You can create a new className for your inputs, and set them to width 40%, then play with flex space-between:

.side-by-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.side-by-side > .yourInputClass {
  width: 40%;
}